# Using inheritance on jhipster entities

Tags: angularjs, hibernate, jhipster

I have the typical model: Employee and it's subclasses RegularEmployee and ContractEmployee

[image: the typical model]

**how can I deal with this in jhipster?** 
I did a JOINED inheritance strategy on hibernate. that was a no brainer. But I can't get jhipster to save the RegularEmployee instance to the database.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, apparently was easier than I thought.

*Example using InheritanceStrategy.JOINED*

**First Step**

generate your three classes Employee and it's subclasses RegularEmployee and ContractEmployee as if they were separate classes, *except* for the fact that you won't be repeating the inherited attributes on the subclasses.

**Second Step**

Add the annotations on the Employee class to tell hibernate that it's going to be the super class [you can find how to do that here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-inheritance-table-per-subclass-annotation-xml-mapping/)

*REMOVE* the id generation type annotations because your subclasses instances to have the same ID as their parent instance.

```
@Id // this should be gone
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) // this should be gone
@Column(name="id")// this should be gone
private Long id;// this should be gone
```

**Third Step**

add the *extends Employee* to the java **subclasses**.

**Fourth Step**

*here you should be able to use $scope inheritance on angular, but I'm new to it, so I don't know how to do it on the app structure that jhipster uses* **I'll be grateful if someone tells me how to improve this**

on your *contractEmployee-dialog.html* and *regularEmployee-dialog.html* add the inherited fields from Employee, so that you can generate a Model that can be saved properly by hibernate, otherwise you will get validation errors.

**Fifth Step**

Build and test.

Comment: What happens if I update `Regular_Employee` using jdl-studio? Do I lose my manual updates?

Comment: I haven't used JDL-Studio in quite a while but, my guess would be that on the code generation phase you will have some conflicts which you will have to solve yourself.

Comment: The domain language does not yet support it

https://www.jhipster.tech/jdl/